# Setting a cookie

Tags: cookies

I have a drupal 10 website. I have to set a cookie for the first time the user visits the site, a cookie with a  lifetime of 1 year. When the user first visits the website, the cookie is not set, a welcome message block appears, the cookie is then set, then the next time the user visits the site, the cookie is already set so the message block doesn't appear.
I am calling my block in a region using `{{elements.blockId}}`
So I know that I have to check if the cookie exists in the `preprocess_region` and based on its value, i check whether i should print the block or not.

However, I don't know where do I have to set the cookie? In some `page_attachment` function?

I have read this [How do I set a cookie?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202176/how-do-i-set-a-cookie/202182#202182)
And I thought I should use

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

$cookie = new use Cookie('cookie_name', TRUE);
$response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
return $response;
```

But I don't have a controller? Where Can i add this code to return a response?

Comment: Cookies must be set in the context of a response from the backend or using Javascript on the frontend.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin but if I set it in javascript, how would i detect it in twig in the region template? If i use JS, I ll be forced to render the block in all cases in the region template and then hide it  using js .

Comment: Also, FWIW there is probably a contributed module that does this.

Comment: Notice that `new use Cookie()` is not correct. `use` needs to be removed.

Comment: Noted, Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to show a message when the cookie has not been set, you could implement [`hook_page_top()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_top/10).

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_page_top().
 */
function mymodule_page_top(array &$page_top) {
  $messenger = \Drupal::messenger();
  $request = \Drupal::request();

  if (!$request->cookies->get('cookie_name', FALSE) {
    // Show a message using $messenger.
    $messenger->addStatus('Your message');

    // Add the cookie using JavaScript.
    $page_top['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
      ['#tag' => 'script',
        '#value' => 'document.cookie = "cookie_name=1; path=/; expires=' . date(DATE_COOKIE, strtotime("+1 year")) . '"',
      ],
      'mymodule_add_cookie_js',
    ];
  }
}
```

[`system_page_top()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_page_top/10) is an example of `hook_page_top()` implementation that uses the messenger to show messages.
[`big_pipe_page_attachments()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21big_pipe%21big_pipe.module/function/big_pipe_page_attachments/10) is an example of hook implementation that sets a cookie using JavaScript (using `#attached`).

Comment: What a great answer  !! Thanks! However I have a block, contained within a region, that includes my message with a photo.Can i do the same but instead of my_module_page_top, i do preprocess for that region? Or i can't attach a js to a region?

Comment: Plus can i do it in theme not in module so that js will be attached on front only?

Comment: And lastly, does this cookie get cached? Because once i used setcookie php function and the cookie was cached a lot

Comment: A preprocess hook is too late for that. That is why the BigPipe module does not use any preprocess hook for a similar task. As for caching, if the code shown in the answer does not avoid the cookie is cached, you could verify what happens when `$page_top['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'cookies:cookie_name';` (which should avoid the content is cached when the cookie is changed) or `$page_top['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;` (which should avoid the page is cached) is added.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Super detailed answer !

Comment: So I can't do that for a region, I have to use page_top instead of a specific region in block layout

Comment: A cookie is for the full page. You cannot have a cookie that is visible only from a single region, so it does not make any difference from where the cookie is set.

Comment: Thank you again !